# Nodejs: can I set objectMode of stream.Transform like this?

Tags: node.js, stream

can I set objectMode like the following code?
if not, how to fix it?

tks, bro.

```js
class com extends stream.Transform {
    constructor(opt) {
        super(Object.assign({}, {objectMode: true}, opt));
    }
    _transform(chunk, enc, callback) {
        let ret = compiler(chunk);
        this.push(ret);
        callback();
    }
}

let st = fs.createReadStream('./com/a.com');
let wr = fs.createWriteStream('./com/b.com');
let c = new com({objectMode: true});
st.pipe(c).pipe(wr);
```

**run it, and got some error.**
I run it in nodeV6.11.1, but got error:

```js
TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk
    at validChunk (_stream_writable.js:211:10)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:241:21)
    at com.ondata (_stream_readable.js:555:20)
```

anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @mscdex yes, I try it and got some error

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that while the custom Transform class is correctly configured to input and output any values, the `wr` `Writable` stream is expecting `Buffer`s or strings only. So when you `push()` a non-`Buffer`/string, you will receive the error you are currently seeing.

If you want to enable object mode for only one side of the `Transform` stream, then you can set `readableObjectMode` or `writableObjectMode` to `true` instead of `objectMode` (which is the equivalent of setting the previous two to `true`).

Comment: can I set objectMode like this?super(Object.assign({}, {objectMode: true}, opt));

Comment: Yes, but be aware that `opt` can override that `objectMode: true` with that line of code.